# Eigenvector factorization using orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm curious about the following eigenvector factorization representation where $\Sigma$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, $V$ is an orthogonal matrix containing columns $\{ v_1, v_2,..,v_d \}$ (eigenvectors) and $\sqrt{\Lambda}$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\sqrt{\Lambda_1},..,\sqrt{\Lambda_d} $:

$AA^T = V \sqrt{\Lambda}( V \sqrt{\Lambda})^T= V \sqrt{\Lambda} \sqrt{\Lambda}^T V^T= V \Lambda V^T = \Sigma. (1)$

Where, $A = V \sqrt{\Lambda}$ and the following relation holds:

$v_j^Tv_i = \delta_{ij},~~ \Sigma v_i = \lambda_i v_i ~~(2)$

I'm unsure about the justification for the orthogonal representation, but I understand from $AA^T$ that it makes sense that we get a symmetric matrix in return ($\Sigma$) since matrix multiplication with the transpose will return a symmetric matrix. I'm also familiar with the representation you often encounter in linear algebra books: $A = PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ consists of the diagonal eigenvalues and $P$ is a nonsingular matrix consisting of the eigenvectors. From $(1)$ can I then relate $\sqrt{\Lambda} \sqrt{\Lambda}^T = D?$. Guess I'm also confused about the representation in $(1)$ and how it relates to the other more common representation ($A = PDP^{-1}$). (Sorry if the question seems messy).

Comment: To confirm, you are using the definition of $A$ given by $A := V \sqrt{\Lambda}$  right?  Note you wrote " $\Sigma v_i = \lambda_i v_i ~~(2)$" which, despite not exactly specifying what the summation is over, is impossible since the $v_i$ are necessarily linearly independent.

Comment: A is given by $A = V \sqrt{\Lambda}$ that is correct. For (2) $v_i$ is the d-dimensional eigenvectors associated with the $d \times d$ symmetric pos-definite matrix $\Sigma$. Hope that helps